# find max and min from value from any column entire table from Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find out the max and the min length of character values that are there in any columns and in any table in SQL Server 2008.

Also , I am finding the max and min integer values that are percent in any column and any table.

My query is as below:

```
Select max(len(Desc)) from table1
```

Also, I tried

```
 Select max(datalength(Desc)) from table1
```

However, I'm getting error "incorrect syntax near keyword desc".What should be the correct syntax? Is there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: use `[Desc]`, since Desc is keyword you can not use it directly, also it seems that there is missing closing bracket in your query as well.

Comment: [Desc] is getting trited as column name and will not work.

Comment: Show your table structure. Does it have a column name 'Desc'?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [] if it is a key word in SQL Server

```
Select max(len([Desc])) from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you miss `)` after `desc`
Change it to

```
Select max(len([Desc])) from table1
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a typo. However, in my actual query I didn't missed that. I'll correct my question.